# Can human brain do quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-computer, biology

First of all, I know that any math (or computation) a classical computer can do, we human can do with pen and paper at same type of efficiency. Obviously, that is because we tell a classical computer what to do steps by steps, and we are capable of completing each step.

My question is whether it is true with quantum computer as well? I guess not?

For a quantum computer, do we take advantage of the mathematical behavior of the quantum world, and use it like a magical box that take input and output something straight for us without any computation occuring? Are we cheating computation with real world experiment? We just exploit physics to construct a function that bypass the computation steps which would be too much for classical computer to do?

Comment: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3

Comment: Note that there is a [Quantum Computing StackExchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I really want the answer to this question to be "yes and no."

Comment: Given that in a millisecond my computer can factor integers that took mathematicians years to factor, it don't think brains and computers operate at the same type of efficiency (even in a complexity theoretic sense)

Comment: The brain is definitely not *doing* quantum computation. One could ask if there are quantum effects play any role in the brain, the answer is likely no, but serious physicists have thought about this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05929

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you actually can't.

1. First of all we have no idea whether something the size of a neuron can actually be in a superposition or interfere (essential for quantum computers). Even if they do, the effect is going to be very small, and it won't work for quantum computing. Qubits are made of electrons and photons, and when you compare a subatomic particle to a cell, the size difference is too large to do any quantum experiments in it. In fact, we have just only figured out how to do interference with molecules.
2. Second, it has been never noticed in observation. There has been no event in which a person actually did this.
3. Third, the information excess. If only part of the neurons started to do 'quantum computing' the information would be too much to handle even for the brain. 2 qubits can store and process 4 bits of information, and the number increases exponentially. That is why, doing so with billions of 'qubits' would be too much information for the brain to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Penrose notably thinks so, most don't.

Here is Max Tegmark's reasoning against it from Our Mathematical Universe pg. 207:

"an individual neuron must be able to be in a superposition of firing and not firing...so how long could a neuron keep secret whether it was firing or not?...10^-20 seconds"

He then uses another model of Penrose's for microtubules and gets 10^-13 seconds or requiring 10,000,000,000,000 thoughts per second.